# Play: How to implement vermongo with ReactiveMongo

Tags: json, mongodb, scala, playframework, reactivemongo

I want to update a JSON document in MongoDB like this:

```
{
  "_id":{"$oid":"52dfc13ec20900c2093155cf"},
  "email": "joe@domain.com",
  "name": "joe",
  "_version": 2
}
```

... and want to create a vermongo document like this on each update:

```
{
   "_id { "_id":{"$oid":"52dfc13ec20900c2093155cf"}, "_version": 1},
   "email": "joe@domain.com",
   "name": "joe",
   "_version": 1,
   "_timestamp" : "2014-02-02T00:11:45.542"
}
```

I've tried a solution like this:

```
trait MyDao {

  ...

  private val shadowCollection = ReactiveMongoPlugin.db.collection[JSONCollection](
    collection.name + ".vermongo"
  )

  private def toVersioned(deleted: Boolean) = __.json.update(
    (__ \ '_id).json.copyFrom((__ \ '_id \ '$oid).json.pickBranch) andThen
    (__ \ '_id \ '_version).json.copyFrom((__ \ '_version).json.pick) andThen
 // (__ \ '_version).json.put(if (deleted) JsString(s"deleted:$version") else JsNumber(version)) andThen
    (__ \ '_timestamp).json.put(Json.toJson(LocalDateTime.now))
  ) 

  private def version(doc: JsValue, deleted: Boolean): Future[LastError] = {
    shadowCollection.insert(doc.transform(toVersioned(deleted)).get)
  }
}
```

The `toVersioned` method has three problems:

Line 1: It doesn't create the multi-fields `_id`

Line 2: It crashes when I try to create `_version` as the second field of `_id`

Line 3: (commented out) if parameter `deleted` is `true`, I'd like to mark the document as deleted by replacing `"_version": 1` with `"_version": "deleted:1"`; it is not clear to me how to handle the condition here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fantastic question; I'd been meaning to learn about [Play's JSON transformers](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJsonTransformers) for ages, and finally a great situation to try them out.

I should note that I was completely unable to get this to work correctly until I added the all-important `functional.syntax._` import:

```
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
```

The solution started out from the *Gizmo* -> *Gremlin* transformer example on the transformers page; that's where I got the usage of the `and` and `reduce`, which completely transforms (pardon the pun) how the whole thing works.

So here it is:

```
private def toVersioned(deleted: Boolean) = (__.json.update(
  ( __ \ '_id ).json.copyFrom((__ \ '_id \ '$oid).json.pickBranch) and
  ( __ \ '_id \ '_version).json.copyFrom((__ \ '_version).json.pick) and
    (__ \ '_version).json.update(
      of[JsValue].map { case JsNumber(oldVersion) =>
        if (deleted) JsString(s"deleted:$oldVersion") else JsNumber(oldVersion)
      }
    ) and
    (__ \ '_timestamp).json.put(Json.toJson(LocalDateTime.now)) reduce
  )
  andThen
  ( __ \ '_id \ '$oid ).json.prune
)
```

Key points:

- I couldn't (within a reasonable amount of time) achieve a "move" of the `_id` node in the one transform, hence the first pass copies it "down" one level, and the second pass (after the `andThen`) deletes the old `$oid`. There's almost-certainly a way...
- The use of `and` seems to change the scope of the `copyFrom`, allowing the `_version` to be picked out of the top-level correctly - when using `andThen` it seemed to only work if descending into nodes "below" the target
- I'm quite happy with the handling of `deleted` here - the `map` seems both Scala- and PlayJSON-idiomatic. The `Of[JsValue]` is necessary because we return either a `JsString` or a `JsNumber` here, and `JsValue` seemed like a suitable superclass

Comment: ... fantastic answer ;-) It works and does exactly what I need. I just had to arrange things to remove the warning "match may not be exhaustive." A big thanks!